# Has anyone met this "$q$-character" table for $S_4$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-groups, symmetric-functions, hecke-algebras, q-analogs

Is anyone aware of the following $q$-character table for the
symmetric group $S_4$?

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mathrm{conj}\backslash\mathrm{rep}       
        & 2+1+1 & 3+1   & 2+2       & 1+1+1+1   & 4   \\ \hline
4       &  1    & -q    &  0        & -q        & q^2 \\ \hline
2+2     & -1    & -1    &  q\,[2]_q &  q        & q   \\ \hline
3+1     &  0    &  0    & -1        &  q        & q   \\ \hline
2+1+1   & -1    &  q    &  0        & -1        & q   \\ \hline
1+1+1+1 & [3]_q & [3]_q & [2]_q     &  1        & 1   \\ \hline
\end{array}

As usual $[n]_q$ denotes the $q$-integer $1 + q + \dotsb + q^{n-1}$ where $q$ is a parameter and $n$ is a positive integer.
The usual character table of $S_4$ is recovered by making the
specialization $q=1$. The rows are orthogonal
with respect to the pairing

\begin{equation}
\langle \Bbb{u} , \Bbb{v} \rangle :=  \
\sum_{\lambda \, \vdash \, 4} \, a(\lambda) \, u_\lambda v_\lambda
\end{equation}

where $\Bbb{u} = (u_\lambda)_{\lambda \, \vdash \, 4} $ and $\Bbb{v} = (v_\lambda)_{\lambda \, \vdash \, 4}$ are vectors
and

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\lambda \, \vdash \, 4       
& 2+1+1 & 3+1   & 2+2       & 1+1+1+1   & 4   \\ \hline
a(\lambda)      
&  q^2    & q    &  q        & q        & 1   \\ \hline
\end{array}

Furthermore the columns are orthogonal
with respect to the pairing

\begin{equation}
(\Bbb{u} , \Bbb{v}) := \
\sum_{\lambda \, \vdash \, 4} \, b(\lambda) \, u_\lambda
v_\lambda
\end{equation}

where

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\lambda \, \vdash \, 4       
& 2+1+1 & 3+1   & 2+2       & 1+1+1+1   & 4   \\ \hline
b(\lambda)      
&  q^{-2} {[3]_q [4]_q \over {[2]_q}}    
&  q^{-1} [3]_q    
&  q^{-1} [2]_q [4]_q       
&  q^{-1} {[3]_q[4]_q \over {[2]_q}}        & 1   \\ \hline
\end{array}

Notice that the entries in the bottom row the table are **not**
the *$q$-dimensions*
of the corresponding irreducible representations of $S_4$ (as defined by the $q$-hook formula). For example
the $q$-hook formula gives $\dim_q(2+2) = 1 + q^2$ as opposed to $[2]_q$ which is what actually appears in this table. From what I can glean in the literature this table is **not** the character table of the Hecke algebra $\mathcal{H}_4(q)$ associated to $S_4$.

thanks, ines.

Comment: It might help if you explained how you got it. E.g., did you $q$-ify the Murnaghan-Nakayama rule?

Comment: The character tables for $S_2$, $S_3$, and $S_4$ coincide, respectively, with the character tables of the Okada algebras $\frak{F}_2$, $\frak{F}_3$, and $\frak{F}_4$ and I have a general recipe for quantizing the Okada characters. I rather not go into the details of that construction, but I'm curious about whether these small rank q-analogues have already appeared (e.g. in MacDonald theory).

Comment: The closest I can think of is a refinement using a descent-statistic on border-strip tableaux, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.13750.pdf